# Android sensor service keep collecting data stop storing data after a while

Tags: android, service, sqlite, sensors

I wrote a small app to collect all sensor data through a running service, when data collected is over certain threshold I will write the data into a SQLite Database, but for some reason, when my service start running, it is working, but after a while, the log still say persist data success but I could not found any more data in the generated SQLite database.

Is there any rules that will put service into stop or limit the size of a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when I use

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

The `calendar.getTime()` will always return the same time which makes me confuse why the data isn't being stored, but actually it is persisted but just tagged with the wrong time.